# Deleted function build fail

Tags: c++

im new to c++ and getting the error on my project that represents a resturant:

> ```
> error: use of deleted function ‘Dish& Dish::operator=(const Dish&)’
>         *__result = *__first;
>
> In file included from /users/studs/bsc/2019/romid/CLionProjects/rest/src/../include/Customer.h:9:0,
>                 from /users/studs/bsc/2019/romid/CLionProjects/rest/src/../include/Action.h:9,
>                 from /users/studs/bsc/2019/romid/CLionProjects/rest/src/Action.cpp:1:
> /users/studs/bsc/2019/romid/CLionProjects/rest/src/../include/Dish.h:19:7: note: ‘Dish& Dish::operator=(const Dish&)’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
> class Dish{
>       ^~~~
> ```

i cant understand which class cause the problem or what is the problem .
this is part the dish.cpp class.

```
 #include "../include/Dish.h";
#include <iostream>

Dish::Dish(int d_id, std::string d_name, int d_price, DishType d_type) : 
id(d_id), name(d_name)
price(d_price), type(d_type){}

int Dish::getId() const
 {
    return id;
}

std::string Dish::getName() const {return name;}

int Dish::getPrice() const {return price;}

DishType Dish::getType() const {return type;}
```

this is the dish.h header file :

```
#ifndef DISH_H_
#define DISH_H_

#include <string>

enum DishType{
    VEG, SPC, BVG, ALC
};

class Dish{
public:
    Dish(int d_id, std::string d_name, int d_price, DishType d_type);
    int getId() const;
    std::string getName() const;
    int getPrice() const;
    DishType getType() const;
private:
    const int id;
    const std::string name;
    const int price;
    const DishType type;
};


#endif
```

Comment: Are any of your member variables constants or references?

Comment: all of them are const ( d_name , d_price , d_type, d_id)

Comment: @DorBirendorf Those are arguments, not members.

Comment: Then how are you intending to assign to them? Remove the const qualifier.

Comment: its a school project and we are not allowed to change that ..
what can be the cause for this problem?

Comment: The problem, according to the error message, is the use of a deleted function. The rest of the message goes on to explain it: `operator=(const Dish&)` is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed. Since the error message ends there an the question doesn't give any details of the `Dish` class it's not possible to say more. Show the definition of `Dish`.

Comment: i added the dish class to the post

Comment: Please, post everything from `class Dish` to the end of this definition.

Comment: Is there a reason you reverted my edits? I was just fixing your formatting to make your code readable

Comment: sorry im new in stackoverfllow , i  meant to do the opposite thing and apply youre edits

Comment: no need to approve edits from users with high reputation they are applied automatically, you only need to approve edits from newer users

Answer (score 1):

The class `Dish` contains constant members like `const int id;`. Therefore there will be no usable automatically defined assignment operator, because assigning one `Dish` to another one would require their `id`s to be assigned as well, but of course `const` does not allow changing the value.

Therefore you are not allowed to use assignment of one `Dish` to another until you provide a user-defined assignment operator.

In particular thinks like

```
Dish a(...);
Dish b(...);
b = a;
```

will trigger the error. You are doing something like that somewhere in your code.

Comment: how can i found where i assign a dish ? 
its a big project and the error message dont give any info

Comment: @DorBirendorf All the lines `In file included from [...],  from [...]` etc. in the error message tell you exactly where. The numbers after the file names are the line number and column number. Just look there and if you don't see why these particular lines are responsible, you an add them to your question.

Answer (score 1):

As the members of `Dish` are `const` the compiler is not able to automatically generate an assignment operator as it can't change the members of an existing object.

You could try to write your own assignment operator but you would run into the same issue. You either need to make the members non-const or stop calling the assignment operator.